# Selling my own PHP script

Tags: php

Right now I'm learning how to program in PHP. I'm trying to reach a point where I can build something such as a calendar, chat box, comment section, ext and sell it on a site such as code canyon. I talked to an "Advisor" on Codecademy and he said that it would be very hard to do that without working with a team. Is there any validity to that? I don't see why I could not build my own calendar to schedule appointments on that I built by myself once I have been working with PHP for six months to a year.

Comment: Validating what someone said is going to be opinion based which is off topic for SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you can try to `sell` your code to a company, so let's say you've made a calendar that is meant for `Code Canyon` to help **plan** something - but looking up [calendar](https://codecanyon.net/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&term=calendar&as=0&referrer=homepage) in Code Canyon came up with just about 300 plugins, it's like trying to make a new framework that isn't as **great** as the current frameworks, so you'll wanna get some source code from those already out-there `Calendars` and pick it apart and understand it, then make your own version of it, if you have all the current functionality for the Calendar and add something to it, it's already better than what's on the market.

To simplify what I said, you wanna bring something new, I'm sure Code Canyon wouldn't buy a plugin from you if it wasn't as great as their current ones.

Hope it helps, and hope to see some plugins from you soon. :)